# How to bypass conversion const char* to int

Tags: c++

I want to write a function

```
template <class Arg>
tuple<int, double> calc(Arg arg);
```

It returns:

```
[arg,0] if arg is int,
[0,arg] if arg is double 
and [0,0] if arg is nor int or double.
```

I implement this function comparing the type of **arg** (Arg), type of **i** (int) and type of **d** (double) and **then equating i=arg or d=arg** respectively.
But if I want to use my function with a string or another type, which can not be converted to int/double, I have a conversion error (its clear, cause I can't equate char* to int, for example).
**How can I bypass this conversion const char* to int** (or another inconvertible type to int)? Or maybe there is another implementation of this function?

```
#define GETTYPE(x) typeid(x).name()
template <class Arg>
    tuple<int,double> calc(Arg arg)
    {
        int i = 0;
        double d = 0;
        if (GETTYPE(arg) == GETTYPE(i))
        {
            i = arg;
        }
        else if (GETTYPE(arg) == GETTYPE(d))
        {
            d = arg;
        }
        return make_tuple(i, d);
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `typeid::name`. It's much better to use `std::is_same` in this situation

Comment: Please post the exact error message and show how you invoke the template. At a quick glance, `template <class Arg>` is usually specified as `template <typename Arg>`, as `double` and `float` aren't classes.

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed it

Comment: @KenY-N in this context, `class` and `typename` are treated the same in current standard, so your advice does not apply. `class` will happily be deduced to primitive types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not need a C++17 code, you can use overloading

```
tuple<int, double> foo(int a) {
    return {a, 0.0};
}

tuple<int, double> foo(double a) {
    return {0, a};
}

template<typename T>
tuple<int, double> foo(T) {
    return {0, 0.0};
}
```

If you need a C++17 code :

```
template<typename T>
tuple<int, double> foo([[maybe_unused]] T a) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, T>)
        return {a, 0.0};

    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<double, T>)
        return {0, a};

    else
        return {0, 0.0};
}
```

Comment: You need a `constexpr` after your `else if` in your `C++17` version.

Comment: Are you sure? This code compile with clang and gcc and msvc

Comment: have you tried calling `foo("const char* arg")` in main?

Comment: It really shouldn't. See [my question and the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356341/do-i-need-to-put-constexpr-after-else-if) to see why. With `const char*` as an argument, the `return {0, a}` will be compiled (since it's **not** `constexpr`) and even though `std::is_same_v<double, T>` will yield `false`, the `return` statement has to be compiled. How are you compiling the code and what is **the exact code** you are compiling?

Comment: Okay I used constexpr function. Thanks, I fixed it ;).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to just have 3 separate overloads:

```
tuple<int, double> calc(int arg)
{
  return make_tuple(arg, 0.);
}

tuple<int, double> calc(double arg)
{
  return make_tuple(0, arg);
}

template < typename T >
tuple<int, double> calc(T arg)
{
  return make_tuple(0, 0.);
}
```

Alternatively you can use template specialisations:

```
template < typename T >
tuple<int, double> calc(T arg)
{
  return make_tuple(0, 0.);
}

template <>
tuple<int, double> calc< int >(int arg)
{
  return make_tuple(arg, 0.);
}

template <>
tuple<int, double> calc< double >(double arg)
{
  return make_tuple(0, arg);
}
```

Comment: Your first solution seems to be a kind of copy and past of my answer

Comment: @AntoineMorrier No copy-paste. Any experienced C++ programmer can write that.

Comment: Copy and past was a mis way to say what I wanted to say ^^, I just said that the answer was already given ;)

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Yeah, its not a copy and paste, I started writing it before you posted your answer

Comment: Okay, I know, it is just very poorly said, I am sorry ^^