# Do I need to put constexpr after else-if?

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++17, if-constexpr

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52355930/7151494), I tried to copy and paste (and add testing in `main()`) this code:

```
template<typename T>
std::tuple<int, double> foo(T a) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, T>)
        return {a, 0.0};
    else if (std::is_same_v<double, T>)
        return {0, a};
    else
        return {0, 0.0};
}

int main() {
    auto [x, y] = foo("");
    std::cout << x << " " << y;
}
```

This is very straightforward - if `T` is deduced as `int`, we want to return a tuple of `[a, 0.0]`. If `T` is deduced as `double`, we want to return a tuple of  `[0, a]`. Otherwise, we want to return `[0, 0.0]`.

As you can see, in the `main()` function, I am calling `foo` with `const char*` argument, which *should* result in `x` and `y` being `0`. That is *not the case*.

While trying to compile it, I encountered a strange error:

> error: could not convert '`{0, a}`' from '`<brace-enclosed initializer list>`' to '`std::tuple<int, double>`'

And I was like *what?*. Why on earth would I want that... I specifically used `std::is_same` to enable `return {0, a}` **only** when the type of `a` is deduced as `double`.

So I quickly ran to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) on if-constexpr. At the bottom of the page, above **Notes**, we can see this snippet of code:

```
extern int x; // no definition of x required
int f() {
if constexpr (true)
    return 0;
else if (x)
    return x;
else
    return -x;
}
```

I thought to myself *oookay..? I can't really see what's wrong with the original code. They use the same syntax and semantics...*.

But I was curious. I was curious if maybe something odd (at that time) might fix that issue, so I changed the original code to:

```
template<typename T>
std::tuple<int, double> foo(T a) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, T>)
        return {a, 0.0};
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<double, T>) // notice the additional constexpr here
        return {0, a};
    else
        return {0, 0.0};
}

int main() {
    auto [x, y] = foo("");
    std::cout << x << " " << y;
}
```

And voilà! The code compiled and executed as expected. So, my question is - **Do we need to put `constexpr` after every `if` statement in `if-else` statement in these kind of situations?** Or is it just my compiler? I am using GCC 7.3.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

> Do we need to put constexpr after every if statement in if-else block in these kind of situations?

Yes. The else-if block<sup>1</sup> is a lie :), there are only if blocks<sup>1</sup> and else blocks<sup>1</sup>. This is how your code is seen by the compiler:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, T>)
    return {a, 0.0};
else // {
    if (std::is_same_v<double, T>)
        return {0, a};
    else
        return {0, 0.0};
// }
```

`else if (/*...*/)` is just a formatting convention that everyone uses. As such, you can clearly see that the second `constexpr` is needed.

---

<sup>1</sup>: "block" is not the correct terminology. if is a statement (with optional else part). A block is `{ /*...*/ }`.

Comment: @Fureeish Also note the cppref's example is correct, the missing `constexpr` is there by design to show that you don't have to have a definition of `x` because the else block (see answer) is discarded.

Comment: Question: Defining function `foo` as `constexpr` will make everything inside a `constexpr` or still all `if`s should be decorated with `constexpr`?

Comment: @MarekR The inner `if`'s still need to be decorated. Just because `foo` is `constexpr` doesn't mean that everything inside the function is `constexpr` (as you can still call the function at runtime).

Comment: There are no blocks (`{}`) in the original example, though, except for the ones required for the function definitions. I recommend saying "statements", in keeping with the standard terms.

Comment: @ArneVogel Yeah, I just used the same terminology as the OP. Will change

Comment: @ArneVogel and Rakete111, I also edited the original question to match your comment

Comment: Worth noting that syntactically, this interpretation of `if else` is no different than omitting the `{ }` on another statement like `if(condition) return 0;`

Comment: `else` is not even a statement. It's half of one.

Comment: @T.C. So... it's a state?

Comment: @Barry No, it's an ent.